# Dynamic content not redering in inertisjs vue ssr

Tags: laravel, vue.js, server-side-rendering, inertiajs

In inertia.js vue js ssr setup, dynamic content is not rendering from props within v-for in view-source.

It shows  within v-for div in page view-source

I checked all the configuration and find no issue anywhere, please suggest

Thanks

Comment: provide some code example  that you have tried to fix the issue in your question.

Comment: Please check the code in the below URL

https://imgur.com/a/x0ti8LH

Comment: You need to include the code as code-formatted **text** in your question, not as a screenshot, and not as an offsite resource, and definitely by editing your question, and not by posting an answer.